# Array initialization/assignment confusion

Tags: java

Could someone tell me what is happening below in the `DayPlanner()` default constructor? Below are my prof's notes, but I don't understand why he does `new HomeObject[SIZE];` twice.

```
private HomeObject[] home = new HomeObject[SIZE]; // This is in the DayPlanner class

public DayPlanner() {                             // DayPlanner constructor
        home = new HomeObject[SIZE];
}
```

Comment: The array initialization in the constructor is not necessary (the field initializer will be copied into the constructor anyway)

Comment: Isn' t there a "t" missing?

Comment: I guess only your prof can tell you. I suspect some "teaching" reason since one of the two would suffice.

Comment: Maybe ask the prof not us?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about why some teacher did something legit but superfluous

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake. Probably the `home` array must be instantiated in the constructor.

Comment: This does not answer to the question.